# Use function over groups or factors with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, magrittr

I want to use a function, e.g. `shapiro.test()` over several groups in a dataset.

First I tried

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %$% shapiro.test(wt)$p.value
#> [1] 0.09265499
```

But that did not iterate over the groups as I expected.
Then I tried a function that would output the results as a dataframe, as that was the approach taken for another question here on Stack Overflow.

```
checkNorm <- function(x) {
  return(data.frame(P = shapiro.test(x)$p.value))
}

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %$% checkNorm(wt)
#>            P
#> 1 0.09265499
```

What is the appropriate way to make functions iterate over the groups passed by `group_by()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column to store p-value of each group :

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(p_val = shapiro.test(wt)$p.value)

#   cyl   p_val
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4 0.570  
#2     6 0.131  
#3     8 0.00275
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `summarise()`, which does exactly what I wanted! Thank you for reminding me.